# Kubernetes + Spark Job not Progressing/Stuck

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

I am trying to run pyspark code on Kubernetes cluster.

The application flow should be: read data -> cache -> perform multiple actions, but the job is not progressing at all. It is stuck on the log message:

```
WatchConnectionManager: The resource version -some number- no longer exists. Scheduling a reconnect.
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Hi Sahil, taking a look at this might be helpful to get answers from the community.: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue within Spark, should be fixed in versions 3.0.2, 3.1.0

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24266